# Swift - FireBase - Snapshot - DataService

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot, dataservice

I have some problems retrieving snapshots from my FireBase child ("Users" into my UITextFields and UITextViews

After I retrieve them, I want them to be editable through code in DataService

Can anyone help ??????

```
enter code here
import  UIKit
import Firebase


class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var selectPhoto: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var schoolProfile: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var interestProfile: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var aboutProfile: UITextView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "EDIT PROFILE"
        profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.height / 2
        profileImage.clipsToBounds = true



        // Display data in tabletcells
        if let user = DataService.dataService.currentUser {
            username.text = user.displayName
            email.text = user.email
//            schoolProfile.text = user.School
//            print(user.photoURL)
            if user.photoURL != nil {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOf: user.photoURL!) {
                    self.profileImage.image = UIImage.init(data: data as Data)
                }

            }
        }else {

        }
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String: Any]?) {
            profileImage.image = image
            imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        } 


    }

    // Change profileimage
    @IBAction func selectPhoto(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        resignFirstResponder()
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        }else {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }
        self.present(imagePicker, animated:  true, completion:  nil)
        }

    @IBAction func saveDidTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        var data = NSData()
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage.image!, 0.1)! as NSData
        DataService.dataService.SaveProfile(username: username.text!, email: email.text!, data: data)
    }
}
extension ProfileTableViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String: Any]?) {

        profileImage.image = image
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

Comment: Please replace the screenshot of your code with the actual code as text. Stack Overflow will highlight it automatically and we can then copy/paste it to help/investigate.

Comment: Can you post the actual query you are using? Where is the code for your tableView cell? You have a tableViewController here but you are missing the required methods. Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: @Carsten . Please give more details, your question is not very clear and you just dumped all your code. The smaller you make the case, the better we can assist you.